# Express req.query works fine with GET but not with POST

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodejs with express and trying to use query parameters. For some reason they work fine with  GET but don't work at all with POST.

Here is my route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/get', function (req, res, next) {
    var schemaId = req.query.schemaId;
    console.log("GET: "+schemaId);
  });

router.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {
    var schemaId = req.query.schemaId;
    console.log("ADD: "+schemaId);
  });
```

and here is the app.js itself:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  dotenv.config();
}

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var schemasRouter = require('./routes/schemas');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/schemas',schemasRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

so doing `localhost:3000/schemas/get?schemaId=test` works just fine. "GET: test" is printed.

but doing `localhost:3000/schemas/add?schemaId=test` doesn't print anything in the console.

Seems like a super simple thing and all the examples I have seen successfully use res.query with POST.

Comment: What are you using to do the POST request, you can’t just use a browsers url.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. I now remember you can't. It has been some time since I have done web dev, I'm bit rusty.

Comment: Try using `routes/schemas/add?etc..` as that is what you are setting the route to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but doing localhost:3000/schemas/add?schemaId=test doesn't print anything

Making a request via the browser's URL will **always** send a `GET` request and ***never*** a `POST` request.

Either write a test html page like this:

```
<html><script>
    fetch(url, {method: 'POST'})
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => document.body.innerHTML += res);
</script></html>
```

Or use something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This ..

```
app.use('/schemas',schemasRouter);
```

And This ...

```
var schemasRouter = require('./routes/schemas');
```

So maybe... This ?

```
localhost:3000/routes/schemas/add?schemaId=test
```